# Using regular expressions in Python to parse LaTeX code

Tags: python, parsing, regex

I am trying to write a Python script to tidy up my LaTeX code. I would like to find instances in which an environment is started, but there are non-whitespace characters after the declaration before the next newline. For example, I would like to match

```
\begin{theorem}[Weierstrass Approximation] \label{wapprox}
```

but not match

```
\begin{theorem}[Weierstrass Approximation] 
\label{wapprox}
```

My goal is to insert (using re.sub) a newline character between the end of the declaration and the first non-whitespace character. Sloppily stated, I want to find something like

```
(\begin{evn}) ({text} | [text]) ({text2}|[text2]) ... ({textn}|textn]) (\S)
```

to do a replacement. I've tried

```
expr = re.compile(r'\\(begin|end){1}({[^}]+}|\[[^\]]+\])+[^{\[]+$',re.M)
```

but this isn't quite working. As the last group, it's matching only the last paired of {,} or [,].

Comment: A less complex solution would probably be to write a tokenizer/lexer for LaTeX that splits the input into tokens and copies them one-by-one into a second buffer. As you copy them you can determine whether you want to insert extra spaces or newline. As you loop through each token, if you encounter a '\begin{(\w+)}' token, then enter a state that ensures a newline is inserted before the next non-whitespace token is copied. Attempting to do full-document analysis on a LaTeX document using regular expression is liable to be fragile.

Comment: As always, don't use regex to parse structured languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
import re

s = r'''\begin{theorem}[Weierstrass Approximation] \label{wapprox}

but not match

\begin{theorem}[Weierstrass Approximation] 
\label{wapprox}'''

p = re.compile(r'(\\(?:begin|end)(?=((?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*))\2)[^\S\n]*(?=\S)')

print(p.sub(r'\1\n', s))
```

pattern details:

```
(   # capture group 1
    \\
    (?:begin|end)
    # trick to emulate an atomic group
    (?=(  # the subpattern is enclosed in a lookahead and a capture group (2)
        (?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*
    ))  # the lookahead is naturally atomic
    \2  # backreference to the capture group 2
)
[^\S\n]* # eventual horizontal whitespaces
(?=\S) # followed by a non whitespace character
```

Explanation: if you write a pattern like `(\\(?:begin|end)(?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*)[^\S\n]*(?=\S)` you can't prevent cases that have a newline character before the next token. See the following scenario:

**`(\\(?:begin|end)(?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*)[^\S\n]*`**`(?=\S)` matches:

**`\begin{theorem}[Weierstrass Approximation]`** 
`\label{wapprox}`

But since `(?=\S)` fails (because the next character is a newline) the backtracking mechanism occurs:

**`(\\(?:begin|end)(?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*`**`)[^\S\n]*(?=\S)` matches:

**`\begin{theorem}`**`[Weierstrass Approximation]` 
`\label{wapprox}`

and `(?=\S)` now succeeds to match the `[` character.

An atomic group is a non capturing group that forbids the backtracking in the subpattern enclosed in the group. The notation is `(?>subpattern)`. Unfortunately the re module doesn't have this feature, but you can emulate it with the trick `(?=(subpattern))\1`.

Note that you can use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (that has this feature) instead of re:

```
import regex

p = regex.compile(r'(\\(?:begin|end)(?>(?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*)[^\S\n]*(?=\S)')
```

or

```
p = regex.compile(r'(\\(?:begin|end)(?:{[^}]*}|\[[^]]*])*+[^\S\n]*+(?=\S)')
```